# Multiple form submissions sorted by user

Tags: 7, views, webforms

Here's my case:

I have site with 5 forms. These can be filled in by user assigned with the a 'client' role. They can view and edit their own submissions and fill in forms multiple times, this works all as expected.

Now I'm looking for a way to display *all submissions* of *all forms* filtered by user. So when the site admin clicks on a client he can see a list with all submissions that this particular user has made.

I've been trying to tweak the default webform submissions view, create new views based on user, create a new view based on webform submissions with different relationships and contextual filters,.. unfortunately all without any luck.

I've been looking around but haven't found a good answer yet, I do apologize if I overlooked and this question has already been asked and properly answered.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are doing two different searches:

A. Get all webforms for which a user is the author

B. Get all users

Basically, Views has trouble with this kind of thing, because Views generally deals with one type of entity at a time, and users and webforms are different types of entities.

You can use [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module to put one view inside the other.

Rough outline:

1. Create a view showing all the forms for a given user (filter for the user using a *Contextual filter* on the UID)
2. Create another view showing all users.  Use Views Field View to embed the view created in 1 and supply the UID as the argument.

This view will probably be very slow/performance intensive but since this is mainly for admin purposes hopefully that's ok.

See more details in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246803/5147).